# App authentication with WebApi on External Servers

Tags: security, mobile, asp.net-web-api, api-key, infrastructure

We're looking into writing a mobile app for our company and have a concern as to the infrastructure of how the application will connect with our data.

Our current structure for our web applications is as follows:

- We have an App server which holds our .NET sites, this is externally facing (obviously)
- These .NET sites interact with our API server (which is only accessible by anything on our App server) So this is only internally accessible

A mobile app will not be on our servers, but it will still need to be able to access our API's. What would be the best course of action to be able to still maintain a level of securing our data in our API's while being able to have them externally accessible by a mobile app or any other app that would need data from it?

My initial thoughts would be some sort of API key system, or perhaps API users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should encrypt your API with ssl. You can also use an API management solution. There are some open source options such as: http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/ and API Agility https://apigility.org/